# How to set up access between different subnets in sonicwall?

Tags: subnet, sonicwall

This is
[Network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEqN7.png.).

Sonicwall   TZ 215 wireless-N SonicOS Enhanced 5.9.1.5-16o

> X0(LAN):192.168.0.252 
>   X1(WAN):192.168.0.253
>   X4(LAN):192.168.32.1

Now,I want to using a 192.168.32.x device access 192.168.0.x servers.
How to set up?Routing?NAT?firewall?
I try to using "Public Server Wizard - Quickly configure your DELL SonicWALL to provide public access to an internal server." create a lot of set.
Now I can using 192.168.0.253 access 192.168.0.5 web server is working well.
But I need access other server in 192.168.0.x.
Can I access 192.168.0.5 directly using 192.168.0.5 address.
Thank for your help!

Comment: No. Your sonic wall isn’t even configured properly. You can’t have the same network address 192.168.0.x on two different interfaces. Please correct the typo if it is, or study up on basic network subnetting. There has to be a different network address on ALL interfaces on a router.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest.But if I use different interfaces,I need changer more computer setting,Tell everybody IP address is changed.Can I Keep the original network subnet unchanged and using it?

Answer (score 0):

I agree - you need separate LAN and WAN networks.  x4 will need to be a different zone too.  Then you will need an access rule that allows traffic from x4 to x0.